# Automator To "Get Specified Text" then select text and then input keystroke

Tags: applescript, automator

OK total newb here but this should be pretty simple.

I want to make a little automator script to make a "new day one entry" in my services menu on mac.

So I have text, I need to select this text and then have automator run the keystroke Command+D

Please help!

So far I have the code for the keystroke, I just can't figure out how to make the Automator function "Get Specified text" text to become "selected" so that I can run the applescript.

[Here is my automator script so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfdiZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/MakeaSystem-WideService.html

First problem I see is that you don't seem to have chosen a document type of "Service" (in Automator).  (You should see 'Service receives selected ...' in the title bar.)

You'll need this structure for your AppleScript even though you are not processing the input (the text you have already selected which is picked-up by the system as selected not as a specific parameter for the script).

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "d" using command down
    end tell
end run
```

I don't have Day One, so I can't tell you what's correct, but it does not appear that Cmd-D is the correct code for a new entry from what I have found on the web.

Finally, if you are substituting a service to select from a contextual menu is that quicker than just doing the keyboard shortcut?